# GUI building and using different classes Java

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

So I'm starting a new project and I was wondering how can I setup multiple classes for my different JPanels. It looks very messy in one class. Let me show you the example. I would like  the JPanel for a menu screen in it's own class.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;


public class TakeAwayLogin {

    private JFrame frmTakeAwaySystem;
    private JTextField textFieldId;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @return 
     */
    public void login() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TakeAwayLogin window = new TakeAwayLogin();
                    window.frmTakeAwaySystem.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TakeAwayLogin() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmTakeAwaySystem = new JFrame();
        frmTakeAwaySystem.setTitle("Take Away System Alpha");
        frmTakeAwaySystem.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frmTakeAwaySystem.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmTakeAwaySystem.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        final JPanel panelLogin = new JPanel();
        frmTakeAwaySystem.getContentPane().add(panelLogin, "name_254735117500687");
        panelLogin.setLayout(null);
        panelLogin.setVisible(true);

        final JLabel lblIncorrect = new JLabel("Incorrect login, try again");
        lblIncorrect.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblIncorrect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 9));
        lblIncorrect.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblIncorrect.setBounds(148, 74, 139, 14);
        panelLogin.add(lblIncorrect);
        lblIncorrect.setVisible(false);

        final JPanel panelPassword = new JPanel();
        frmTakeAwaySystem.getContentPane().add(panelPassword, "name_254738265432897");
        panelPassword.setLayout(null);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(112, 157, 205, 41);
        panelLogin.add(passwordField);
        passwordField.setHorizontalAlignment(JPasswordField.CENTER);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Lock Application");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panelPassword.setVisible(false);
                panelLogin.setVisible(true);
                passwordField.setText("");
                textFieldId.disable();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(135, 155, 172, 50);
        panelPassword.add(btnNewButton);
        panelPassword.setVisible(false);

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String login = textFieldId.getText();
                char[] pass = passwordField.getPassword();
                String p = new String(pass);
                String password = "pass";
                if (login.equalsIgnoreCase("milan") &&  p.equals(password)) {
                    panelPassword.setVisible(true);
                    panelLogin.setVisible(false);
                }else {
                    lblIncorrect.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
        btnLogin.setBounds(160, 209, 97, 41);
        panelLogin.add(btnLogin);

        textFieldId = new JTextField();
        textFieldId.setBounds(112, 88, 205, 43);
        panelLogin.add(textFieldId);
        textFieldId.setColumns(10);
        textFieldId.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        JLabel lblId = new JLabel("Enter the business login:");
        lblId.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblId.setBounds(112, 63, 205, 14);
        panelLogin.add(lblId);


        JLabel lblEnterYourPassword = new JLabel("Enter your password");
        lblEnterYourPassword.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblEnterYourPassword.setBounds(148, 142, 139, 14);
        panelLogin.add(lblEnterYourPassword);

        JPanel panelPizza = new JPanel();
        frmTakeAwaySystem.getContentPane().add(panelPizza, "name_254741096954780");

    }
}
```

So help would be great.

Thanks very much.

Comment: _" I would like the JPanel for a menu screen in it's own class."_ - So what's the problem? Why don't you just do it?

Comment: I mean I still wouuld like it to link. Sorry if this seems confusing.

Basically say the actionPerformed for the btnNewButton I would like that in a different class.

Comment: link how? Define _"link"_

Comment: I would like that code in the other class and for it to be able to work as it does now.

Comment: Ok but why _would_ it not work? What have you attempted that that would make you think it doesn't work? Basically what you're asking if how can we help you refactor your entire code, which is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why creating a second class would be necessary. If you just want the code to look less messy, then add comment separators between Panels or something to that effect. I think that splitting up the Panels into their own classes would be just cause you to have to write more calls to be able to create the same functionality. But if you must, then make a class within your initiate class and work from there.

Comment: I'm planning on adding quite a few classes. Can you explain how I would do what you're explaining? ~Thanks

Comment: Well, within your class you can create other classes. If you want a class to create each Panel, then create each class and then make a static method within each class to create their respective Panel. Each of these methods will create its own Panel, and then from there you can do whatever functions you want.

Comment: Hi Alex, would you mind giving me an example as to where I put this? Is it something like public static Name() { //code }

Comment: You should be able to do it like this if I understand your goal: public class MainClass() { /*All your code*/ public class PanelCreator () { public static initializePanel() { /*create JPanel*/} ---- and then back in your main class you could make a static method call like PanelCreator.initializePanel();----I don't know if this helps or hurts, but if it doesn't help, look up nesting classes and static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying, you want something like:

```
public class MyMainJFrame extends JFrame{
     private JPanel panel1 = new MyFooPanel();
     private JPanel panel2 = new MyBarPanel();

     public MyMainPanel(){
         initialize();
     }

     void initialize(){
         //init the JFrame
         this.setTitle("Take Away System Alpha");
         this.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
         this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         this.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

         //and add the panels
         this.add(panel1);
         this.add(panel2);
     }
}

// a file for each one

public class MyFooPanel extends JPanel{
     private JButton button;
     //... add components and logic
}

public class MyBarPanel extends JPanel{
     private JTextField field;
     //... add components and logic
}
```

If you want to use specific methods for each custom panel, then change the type of variable for the same name of the custom class.